# Why is the function that follows `awaited` function not triggered

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have the following setup:

```
async function f1() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(1);
        }, 2000)
    });
}

function f2() {
    console.log(2);
}


async function f() {
    await f1();
    f2();
}

f();
```

I get only `1` logged to the console. The second function `f2` is never triggered. Why?

#### EDIT:

Silly typo. I put the `resolve()` there but it was stolen along the way by some mystical creature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call resolve() in your promise.

Comment: I can swear I had it there) Silly typo. Anyways, thanks